# Listing IDs of all selected features with expression in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, features, select-by-attribute, qgsexpression

I would like to get an array with IDs of all selected features of layer *'LayerB'* (field-name: `"id_of_layerB"`) as a default value in a QGIS Attribute form of *'LayerA'*.

I tried something like:

```
aggregate(layer:='LayerB',
          aggregate:='array_agg',
          expression:= "id_of_layerB",
          is_selected('LayerB', ???)
          )
```

but I have no idea how to realize this (especially what to put in the `???`-part of the expression part of the code.

I think, the `is_selected()`-function checks agains just one feature, but is there a way to get ALL (one or more) selected features of *'LayerB'*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to adjust your expression like this:

```
string_to_array(
    aggregate(@layer,
              aggregate:='concatenate',
              expression:=to_string("id"),
              filter:=is_selected(),
              concatenator:=','),
    delimiter:=',')
```

[image: result3]

Comment: I've no idea why code works just in some layers in my project. There are several layers where code does not work (type: character varying[]). Same code is copied from one layer and its fieldcalculator to another by copy and paste with different results/previews:['1','2'...] or ['']

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, one may try using a short PyQGIS code:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
selection = layer.selectedFeatures()
ids = [feature['id'] for feature in selection]
```

[image: result]

Comment: But how to add this code in a expession? Modifed code. But still does not work: aggregate(
layer:= 'LayerB',
aggregate:='array_agg',
expression:="id_of_layerB",
filter:=is_selected('LayerB' , get_feature_by_id('LayerB',$id))=True)

Answer (score 2):

One can also apply the [`concatenate()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#concatenate) function:

```
string_to_array(
    concatenate(
        to_string("id"),
        filter:=is_selected(),
        concatenator:=','
        ),
    delimiter:=',')
```

[image: result1]

Comment: I'd prefer your first approach (string_to_array(aggregate(@layer...) because the array shall be stored in another layer

Answer (score 2):

Another possible expression:

```
array_filter(
    array_foreach(generate_series(0, layer_property(@layer, 'feature_count')-1),
        if(is_selected(get_feature_by_id(@layer, @element)), attribute(get_feature_by_id(@layer, @element), 'id'),'***')
        ),
    @element != '***')
```

[image: result2]

Comment: seems to have a slower performance on large layers

Comment: yes, you are right. because it involves a bit more functions than other approaches

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use Python in the Field Calculator via the [Function Editor](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html#function-editor)

```py
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import iface

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def ids(field, feature, parent):
    layer = iface.activeLayer()
    selection = layer.selectedFeatures()
    ids = [feature[field] for feature in selection]
    return ids
```

[image: python]

and get the output

[image: result]

*Note:* That function `ids('id')` reads field with a single parenthesis i.e. `'`.

Comment: I'd prefer your first approach (string_to_array(aggregate(@layer...) because the layer may not be selected in my case

Comment: Shall I delete other solutions that are not working for you?

Answer (score 2):

Used the pyqgis-code from @Taras, renamed some arguments and added some flexibility (layerName as argument) and a check against unique layername and added a helptext :

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *


@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')

def selected_content(layerName, field, feature, parent):
    """
    Returns a array of field-contents of selected features<br><br>
    Returns <br><br><span class=\"argument\">string </span>Array of field-contents
    <br>
    <h4>Syntax</h4><br>
    <code><span class=\"functionname\">selected_features</span> <span class=\"argument\">(string, string)</span></code><br>
    
    <h4>Arguments</h4><br>    
    <span class=\"argument\">string </span>UNIQUE layer name <br>
    <span class=\"argument\">integer </span>field name <br>
    <h4>Example</h4><br>    
    <ul> 
      <li><code>selected_content('myLayerName','myFieldName')</code> &rarr; <code>'['a','b']'</code>
    </ul>

    """
    layer = layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layerName)
    if len(layer)>1:
        content=['invalid layer name (not unique)']
    else:
        selection = layer[0].selectedFeatures()
        content = [feature[field] for feature in selection]
    return content
```